# pyautogui problem : locateCenterOnScreen is not finding the right location

Tags: pyautogui

I'm trying to code a simple work automation program, 
with locateCenterOnscreen code in order to find the spot to click,
do some simple click and copy-paste job, and repeat those jobs for many times.

In doing so, I have a problem as follows:

It works just fine from time to time, 
but sometimes locateCenterOnScreen code finds a wrong spot.
If I restart & clear output and try again, sometimes it works fine again,
but sometimes it still finds a wrong spot.

It still finds some spot so the program runs without an error.
But it's a totally wrong spot, on which doesn't have any image, so I don't believe it's a image problem.

I'm using dual monitor, can that be a problem?
If so, what should I do to fix this problem?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and here's my code.

```
import time
import pyautogui as p


def alttab():
    p.keyDown('alt');p.press('tab');p.keyUp('alt')

sku_code = p.locateCenterOnScreen("sku_code.png")
bd_code = p.locateCenterOnScreen("mag.png")
add_to_list = p.locateCenterOnScreen("add_to_list.png")

alttab()

for i in range(10):

    p.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    p.moveTo(bd_code);p.moveRel(-30,);p.click()
    p.hotkey('ctrl', 'v');p.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)

    alttab()
    p.press('right');p.press('right');p.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

    p.click(sku_code)
    p.hotkey('ctrl', 'a');p.press('delete');p.hotkey('ctrl', 'v');p.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)

    alttab()
    p.press('right');p.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

    p.moveTo(add_to_list)
    p.moveRel(7, 45);p.click()
    p.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    p.click(add_to_list)
    time.sleep(2)
    error = p.locateCenterOnScreen("error.png")

    # if everything goes fine to this point, it doesn't generate any pop-up, 
    # but if something goes wrong, it would generate a pop-up with "error.png" image.


    if error != None:
        p.press('enter')
        alttab()
        p.press('right');p.press('f2');p.typewrite("error");p.press('enter')
        p.press('left');p.press('left');p.press('left');p.press('left')

    else:
        p.press('enter')
        alttab()
        p.press('right');p.press('f2');p.typewrite("success");p.press('enter')
        p.press('left');p.press('left');p.press('left');p.press('left')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey I Believe I have a answer for your problem:**

- You could use a clearer image with no extra noise 
  this may be causing your problems
- also instead of using

  ```
   sku_code = p.locateCenterOnScreen("sku_code.png")
  ```

try using confidence value

```
    sku_code = p.locateCenterOnScreen("sku_code.png", confidence=o.9)
```

just make sure to have openCV installed 
and if it gives an error use a try except block in a for while loop
and iterate over

```
def iterate(number_of_iterations, interval)
counter = 0
while counter <= number_of_iterations:
    time.sleep(float(interval))
    try:
        x,y = p.locateCenterOnScreen("sku_code.png", confidence=o.9)
        p.click(x, y)
        break
    except TypeError:
        pass
        counter += 1
```